# Send email if user hasn't logged in for X amount of time

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to do the following:

1. Find out when a user last logged into Wordpress.
2. If it's longer than X amount of time then send an email alert.

Essentially the idea is to encourage users to log in and update the website.

I've found [this](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-last-login/) plugin which gives me the last login time. I can also use `wp_mail();` to send emails but how would I trigger all that / continually check it the last login date?

Comment: Please give your users a way to opt-out this feature.

Answer (score 1):

With the plugin you mentioned, you'll have a new database column in your `wp_users` table, which gives you a good starting point.

Next, as @bswatson mentioned, you can leverage WP Cron to run a task that checks for inactive users (if low site traffic is a concern, you might consider [setting up WP Cron to use a real cron job](https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/)). The daily task would look something like this:

1. Collect all users from the database who haven't logged in in the last X days or more.

   - You might consider installing the plugin before rolling out the cron task, or risk emailing **everyone**.
   - As you probably don't want to spam people daily, I'd recommend adding a bit of user meta to indicate this person has been emailed already; you can filter out those users as you build your list of people to email, then delete that user meta when the user logs in.
   - Depending on the size of your WordPress site, you'll probably want to limit this to only a few users; it might make sense to email admins and editors (people with publishing capabilities) but maybe not authors/contributors/subscribers. If you need to email large numbers of people, I'd recommend batching (you can even register cron jobs from within cron jobs) to avoid sending out dozens/hundreds/thousands of emails at once.
2. Loop through the users, emailing them using `wp_mail()` to nudge them to log in.

   - Once an email is sent, add a bit of user meta to prevent duplicate emails.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what options you have on your hosting. I don't know how to do it purely in WordPress (and I don't know if something like that is possible).

But I would use some `cron` job to run some small script. If you can use system cron, of course.

EDIT:
I found [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-reminder/) WP plugin. But as I suspected, it depends on users visiting your website. So if you want to send emails independently on your website traffic, then you need to use some OS solution.

Comment: To piggy-back on what everis said, an easy way to fire cron jobs without even touching your OS would be to use a free account on easycron.com -- You can set it up to 'ping' your site every hour or so and run your script / plugin.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a built in system called WP Cron which mimics a system cron, but can be set up and configured directly in code. There are some drawbacks, such as needing traffic to kick of a task.

Here's a pretty thorough breakdown of [how WP Cron works](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/10/schedule-events-using-wordpress-cron/) including some ways to workaround the issues.